# How to check what tablespaces the schemas are using in oracle?

Tags: oracle, tablespace

I want to see how much space my users have and what tablespaces they use. I do this query:

```
   SELECT * 
From
   dba_ts_quotas
```

but my users are missing from the result list.

Where should I look for this info?

Comment: [dba_segments](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/DBA_SEGMENTS.html#GUID-7BF4F8C7-1917-4532-B048-C044E17A1754)?

Comment: Your subject line says you want to check what tablespaces are being used.  But your actual question is about _space_ being used.  Two different questions.  Though, as @AlexPoole points out, either can be answered by a proper query of dba_segments.